# Default argument enforcing type identity

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have custom class (actually simple wrapper for `heapq`) that wraps the interface into object-oriented one and allows for optional `key` and `cmp` arguments.

In order to implement type checks I have introduced `Tv` (type of values within the heap) and `Tk` (types of "keys" of values -- i.e. what is going to be compared within the heap).

Thus the annotation of the `__init__` looks like this:

```
from typing import *

Tv = TypeVar('Tv')
Tk = TypeVar('Tk')

class Heap(Generic[Tv, Tk]):
    def __init__(self, initial: Optional[Iterable[Tv]],
                 key: Callable[[Tv], Tk] = lambda x: x, cmp: Callable[[Tk, Tk], bool] = op.lt):
        pass
```

Unfortunately, `mypy` reports and error in this case:

```
error: Incompatible default for argument "key" (default has type "Callable[[Tv], Tv]", argument has type "Callable[[Tv], Tk]")
```

Since the specification of what is `Tk` is of little use for whoever is going to use the `Heap` I tried to drop it entirely -- I made `Heap` subclass just `Generic[Tv]` and set `Tk = Any`. This had nice side-effect that the user of `Heap` wouldn't need to specify `Tk` type, which is mostly same as `Tv`, but I lost all the type checks on `Tk` within my implementation.

Is there a way to keep type-checks for `Tk` within the `Heap` and make the default key value of `lambda x: x` do not raise an error?

edit: When I tried to make `Heap` subclass just `Generic[Tv]` and keep the `Tk = TypeVar('Tk')` I still got the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inferred type of `lambda x: x` is `Callable[[Tv], Tv]`, since there is nothing in the function that can change the type of `x` before returning it. This violates the type hint that says the argument and return types can vary arbitrarily.

Once fix is to use `cast` to tell `mypy` that the default function can "change" its argument type as necessary.

```
class Heap(Generic[Tv, Tk]):
    def __init__(self, 
                 initial: Optional[Iterable[Tv]],
                 key: Callable[[Tv], Tk] = lambda x: cast(Tk, x),
                 cmp: Callable[[Tk, Tk], bool] = op.lt):
        pass
```

However, this basically tells `mypy` that you know what you are doing, and that if a `key` function isn't supplied, that *you* will ensure that a value of type `Tv` can actually be used as a value of type `Tk`. In general, there is *no* function with type `Callable[[Tv], Tk]` for arbitrary types `Tv` and `Tk`.